# Sanitize not working for the 'p' and 'br' tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I have a text:

```
<p>This is some text <br/> with two<br /> lines</p>
```

Here's output I expect:

```
This is some text <br/> with two<br /> lines
```

I'm using helper inside my model (I know, but that is just the way I wanted):

```
result = ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(text, :tags => ['br'])
```

But it doesn't work. I get the result without any tags:

```
This is some text with two lines
```

I have also tried:

```
result = ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(text, :tags => %w(br))
```

But it didn't work.

What's wrong and how can I retrieve  text with `<br/>` tags included?

Comment: Hm, what do you mean by `full_sanitizer` code? That class is part of the helper, I haven't wrote it, just used it

Comment: Do you have this line in the helper `config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_tags = 'br'`?

Comment: I didn't have, and that is because I wanted to specify the tags manually. The answer below worked just great. Thanks for the effort in any case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you try this

```
text = "<p>This is some text <br/> with two<br /> lines</p>"
#=> "<p>This is some text <br/> with two<br /> lines</p>" 
result = ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(text, :tags => ['br'])
#=> "This is some text <br /> with two<br /> lines"
```